# How long Job Manager can store checkpoints?

Tags: apache-flink

Apache Flink allow to store checkpoints in Job Manager memory (`state.backend = jobmanager`).

For example my flow created 1,000,000 checkpoints. All of them will be stored in Job Manager memory or Job Manager will remove old checkpoints periodically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flink will only keep the latest completed checkpoint. All older checkpoints will be discarded and, thus, the memory/resources they occupy will be freed.